# Why cant you have one loop for bubble sort?

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

I was just in an argument with my instructor about bubble sort, he told me that bubble sort is known as two for loops, one nested in the other.  Which was not given before I started the assignment, so okay that is fine, but what is wrong with this code for a bubble sort:

```
int num = 0, i = 0;
bool go = true;
while (i < size - 1){
    if (array[i] > array[i + 1]){
        num = array[i];
        array[i] = array[i + 1];
        array[i + 1] = num;
        go = false;
    }
    i++;
    if (i >= size - 1 && go == false){
        i = 0;
        go = true;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    cout << array[i];
}
```

does it not do the same thing as a bubble sort?

```
int i, j;
bool flag = true;
int temp;
int numLength = size;
for (i = 1; (i <= numLength) && flag; i++)
{
    flag = false;
    for (j = 0; j < (numLength - 1); j++)
    {
        if (array[j + 1] < array[j])
        {
            temp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[j + 1];
            array[j + 1] = temp;
            flag = true;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    cout << array[i];
}

return;
```

Thanks!

Comment: i entered the wrong code, sorry the correct one is in it now!

Comment: Well, probably you can call it a bubble sort, without the inner loop! :P But, what the inner loop was doing for you now you are doing that with `i`, `go` and an extra `if` condition..

Comment: Theoretically, anything can be rewritten as just a single loop. (since that's Turing complete) But it doesn't mean it will be pretty to look at though.

Comment: I understand it isn't as "pretty" but without giving the information of using two nested loops and asking someone to make a program that does what bubble sort does, is my answer not correct?

Comment: This is two loops, just not two for loops.

Comment: I don't know about anybody else but using two for loops to implement bubble sort makes intuitive sense to me. I don't see why you would implement it any other way. Maybe that's why your instructor didn't explicitly tell you to use two nested for loops - because he probably thought it should be fairly obvious.

Comment: As an example of how much less readable the simulated nested loop version is, the code is missing an obvious optimization for bubble sort (for what it is worth :) ). The inner loop can be limited to j < (numlength - i) which will perform a percent better than the other two implementations presented, but it is not immediately obvious how to apply that to the more convoluted code. Not that it can't but it is not obvious.

Answer (score 6):

The bubble sort algorithm needs two loops: the inner one iterating through the items and swapping them if adjacent ones are out of order, the outer one repeating until no more changes are made.

Your implementation *does* effectively have two loops. It's just that one of them is implemented using a flag and if condition, which resets the outer loop variable. It will do the same thing - loop through the items until no more need swapping.

Note, however, that constructing the algorithm in this way does not make it more efficient, or faster, or anything like that. It just makes it harder to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Your last paragraph reminds me of [this article](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/polynomial-optimization).

Answer (score 2):

You need nested loops because one pass through the array will not always sort all the elements.

Your code only *simulates* nested loops by resetting `i` when we've reached the end and still have things left to sort. Theoretically speaking, your code will have the same runtime as a nested bubble sort if given the same input array.

As to the question of whether you *can*; of course you can. But it's important to realize there is no benefit, in practice or in theory, to choosing one form over the other, at least as far as I can tell.

Also, when computing the time complexity of both algorithms, you will come to the conclusion that your algorithm, just like the form with nested loops, will need to perform the operation *at most* `n` times; the operation being a pass through the array, which is on the order of `n`. You will have to convince yourself that this is the case with your algorithm.

So no matter how you slice it (array pun intended, I guess?), bubble sort will have complexity `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically, you can have a one-loop bubble sort. *Conceptually*, you'll still have two loops.

> does it not do the same thing as a bubble sort?

Yes, it does the same thing. Up to and including having a nested loop.

Your argument seems to be that if you only have one `for` loop in your code, you've created a one-loop bubble sort. It's a ruse though; there are still two loops happening algorithmically. And that's really the only thing that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Your code implements bubble sort. I can't see any advantages in your instructors code. Only arguments for two arguments is that it is bad style to change loop variable inside loop and we should avoid it.

And i would change

```
if (i >= size - 1 && go == false)
```

to

```
if (i == size - 1 && go == false)
```

since the first version introduces the misconception that I *can* be greater than size (but it can't)