# What is the name of this Sort Algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

```
var counter = 0;

function sort(arr)
{
    var totalItem = arr.length;
    var temp ;
    var index;
    var isSortDone = true;
    for( index = 0 ; index < totalItem ; index ++)
    {

        if(arr[index] > arr[index+1])
        {
            temp = arr[index];
            arr[index] = arr[index+1];
            arr[index+1] = temp ;

             isSortDone = false; 
        }

        if(arr[totalItem-(1+index)] < arr[totalItem-(2+index)] )
        {    
            temp = arr[totalItem-(1+index)]
            arr[totalItem-(1+index)] = arr[totalItem-(2+index)]
            arr[totalItem-(2+index)] = temp

            isSortDone = false;

        }
        counter++;

    }
    if(isSortDone == true) { console.log(counter + ":Sort is Done", arr); return 0;}

    return sort(arr);
}
```

Comment: Where did you find the `js` ?

Comment: I think it's the quite famous *"wall-of-code with no explanation"* algorithm ?

Comment: I call it slow, since `[1,2,5,3].sort()` would be faster and accomplish the same ordering.

Comment: I was trying to learn bubble sort Algorithms, I didn't like what they have done as an example  so I change the code,  and I end up with this. am not sure if it has a name or not

Comment: @YeneMulatu _"I was trying to learn bubble sort Algorithms, I didn't like what they have done as an example so I change the code, and I end up with this."_ Does this resolves the Question _"What is the name of this Sort Algorithm?"_ ? Only you can name and describe the process if it is actually different than a standard bubblesort ? Can you include comments at `javascript` at Question that indicates what is occurring ?

Comment: "I made up a sort algorithm, can you tell me what it is called?"

Comment: I think I got the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665022/why-cant-you-have-one-loop-for-bubble-sort and  @BJ Myers just WOW

Comment: With `isSortDone` set to `true` only in the declaration, I'd call it "Waitforitsort".

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a recursive bi-directional version of bubblesort (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) similar to this variant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_shaker_sort, but with both loops rolled into one (which doesn't make much of a difference wrt. performance or other characteristics).

Note that each recursive call could omit the first and last item, as they will be the smallest / biggest globally (you could implement this by adding an offset parameter).

Given that there may be up to n recursive calls, this is probably likely to cause a stack overflow.

Comment: I have seen other variation of bubble sort, what I can't find is, one which does bi-directional sort in side a single loop, or  doing it in a single  loop is irrelevant.

Comment: Doing it in a single loop won't have any significant implication on performance, correctness or memory, so I'd say it's irrelevant and your algorithm is basically the same as "Cocktail Shaker Sort" linked above...